# Use list as variable in a for loop to switch data with callback in Plotly Dash

Tags: python-3.x, callback, plotly-dash

I have a dictionary consisting of two keys and lists. I would like to use callback in Plotly Dash to switch the list as variable for display. The list is used in a `for` loop within `children` of `html.Div`. Please find the example below :

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from pathlib import Path
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

my_data = {'fruit_list1': ['apple', 'orange', 'peach'], 'fruit_list2': ['cherry', 'grape', 'strawberry']}
my_list = ['fruit_list1', 'fruit_list2']

def fruit_list(fruitlist):
        return(my_data[fruitlist])

def add_value(fruit):
        return html.P('Type of fruit : ' + fruit)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.P('Select fruit list : '),
        dcc.Dropdown(
                id='change-the-list',
                value='fruit_list1',
                clearable=False,
                options=[
                        {'label': value_input, 'value': value_input} for value_input in my_list]
                ),
        html.Div(
                id='fruit-list',
                children=[add_value(fruit) for fruit in fruit_list('fruit_list1')]
                )
        ])

@app.callback(Output('fruit-list', 'children'),
        Input('change-the-list', 'value'))

def update_list(list_input):
        return {
        # What do I do here to switch from 'fruit_list1' to 'fruit_list2'?
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=8051)
```

In this case, how do I dynamically switch from `'fruit_list1'` to `'fruit_list2'` to reflect the change using `dcc.Dropdown`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I just need to return the whole `children`.

```
@app.callback(Output('fruit-list', 'children'),
        Input('change-the-list', 'value'))

def update_list(list_input):
        children=[add_value(fruit) for fruit in fruit_list(list_input)]
        return children
```